# How to display negative values in a d3 bar chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

Hey :) Despite many attempts using snippets found on the internet, I'm not able to display negative values in a d3 bar chart I've incorporated into a React component. When a negative value is due to render, nothing is displayed.

The component:

```
// npm.
import React from 'react'
import {
  select,
  scaleBand,
  scaleLinear
} from 'd3'

// tmp.
import data from './data'

// styles.
import styles from './styles.scss'

class YearProfitLossBarChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.draw = this.draw.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.draw()
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.draw()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <svg style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', marginBottom: '-4px' }} ref={(node) => {this.node = node}}></svg>
    )
  }

  draw() {
    let bounds = this.node.getBoundingClientRect()
    let width = bounds.width
    let height = bounds.height

    let node = select(this.node)

    let xScale = scaleBand()
    xScale.domain(data.map((d) => d.month))
    xScale.padding(1/8);
    xScale.paddingOuter(0)
    xScale.range([0, width])

    let yScale = scaleLinear()
    yScale.domain([0, Math.max(...data.map((d) => d.value))])
    yScale.range([0, height])

    let bars = node.selectAll('rect').data(data)
    bars.enter()
      .append('rect')
      .merge(bars)
      .attr('x', (d) => xScale(d.month))
      .attr('y', (d) => height - yScale(d.value))
      .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
      .attr('height', (d) => yScale(d.value))
 }
}

export default YearProfitLossBarChart
```

The data structure:

```
export default [
  { month: 'Jan', value: 100 },
  { month: 'Feb', value: 80 },
  { month: 'Mar', value: 100 },
  { month: 'Apr', value: 50 },
  { month: 'May', value: 100 },
  { month: 'Jun', value: 100 },
  { month: 'Jul', value: -100 },
  { month: 'Aug', value: 100 },
  { month: 'Sep', value: 100 },
  { month: 'Oct', value: 100 },
  { month: 'Nov', value: 100 },
  { month: 'Dec', value: 100 }
]
```

I'm not too familiar with d3 as this is the first project I'm using it on, so please excuse me if this is obvious.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

The component renders as follows:

[image]

Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: I think the issue might be that you are setting your Y domain like so: `yScale.domain([0, Math.max(...data.map((d) => d.value))])`, so 0 is the lowest value that will show. Maybe do a similar `Math.min(...)` instead of passing `0`.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately we've tried that and the result is the same... Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, alright. I did find some examples [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2368837) and [here](https://bl.ocks.org/datafunk/8a17b5f476a40a08ed17) in case it helps at all, otherwise hopefully someone else will be able to help more.

Answer (score 1):

Set the domain minimum to 0 if no negative numbers else set it to the minimal data value

```
yScale.domain([ Math.min(0, d3.min(data, d => d.value)), d3.max(data, d => d.value) ])
```

You need to change the calculation of the bar height

```
yScale.range([height, 0]);
let bars = node.selectAll('rect').data(data)
    bars.enter()
      .append('rect')
      .merge(bars)
      .attr('x', (d) => xScale(d.month))
      .attr('y', (d) => yScale(d.value))
      .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
      .attr('height', (d) => height - yScale(d.value))
```